# Function after d in integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How do you interpret this?

$$\int[y-f(x, c)] \text{d}g(x,y)$$

I only saw things such as $\text{d}x\text{d}y$? But here a function ($g$) is after $\text{d}$. c is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,
$$dg(x,y)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)dx+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y)dy$$

Comment: And how should I calculate the primitive function for the above integral then? Or what does it mean intuitively? 2 dimensional integrals can be thougt of as volumes for example but what does this integral mean?

Comment: You can't really say anything about a primitive without knowing exactly what $f$ and $g$ are. I also can't comment on what it means other than going back to the definition of an integral. Certainly an integral need not represent a volume. Perhaps the source where you found it has some explanation.

Comment: I'm on a phone so I can't link articles, but perhaps you should look at the Wikipedia article on differential forms

Answer (score 0):

This seems an instance of the [Riemann-Stieltjes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) integral, in two variables. Primitives of functions are not related to the specific kind of integral that you're dealing with. What happens is that if the function satisfies enough differentiability conditions, then we have results relating the derivative with said integral (e.g., the fundamental theorem of calculus for Riemann and Lebesgue integrals). That being said, everywhere I saw, people only computed *definite* Riemann-Stieltjes integrals.